# Etag Proxy Caching: What does it do?

Tags: c#, caching, proxy, etag

I use ETags to improve performance. In the code I set the Cachability :

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public))
```

I understand that "Public" means Client, Server & Proxy.

But how is this handeled if the client does NOT have a local cache.
Does the Proxy and/or server still validates the ETag with my Website or does the proxy itself just answers "I know this one. No need to ask the server?"

Or in other does the following scenario still work if ETag-Caching on Proxy is enabled?

1. Browser does a request. An ETag "ABBA" is returned
2. Browser does another request to the server. The ETag "ABBA" is recognized, a 304 is returned
   2.1 Browser uses local cache
3. Browser does another request to the server, sending the ETag "ABBA". This time the Server decides that the data has changed, Therefore it returns a new Response with a new Etag.

If a Proxy uses ETAg-Caching does it still ask the server if the Etag is valid or does the request end there if the Proxy once know the etag?